# Can we fetch the metadata `_version` of existing document using Spring-data-elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am implementing a feature where I need to compare the metadata version of an existing document before indexing it and I have a version attribute in my object which can't be the same as the metadata version. Can I fetch the metadata version explicitly in code, so that I can compare ? I am using `spring-data-elasticsearch`. I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add a property annotated with `@Version` to your entity, for example:

```java
@Document(indexName = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @Nullable
    private Long id;

    @Nullable @Version
    Long version;

    // other properties, getter and setter
}
```

When reading entities with Spring Data Elasticsearch, this property - which must be a `Long` - will be set to the value returned from Elasticsearch.